# How do I print the length of each key in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to print the key and its length.

So my desired result would be L1: 4, L2: 2, etc...

Here's the code I have so far. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
dic1 = {'L1': ['NY', 'CT', 'NH', 'MA'], 'L2': ['TX', 'NM'], 'L3': ['CA', 'WA', 'AZ'], 'L4': ['ND', 'SD','WY', 'ID'], 
'L5':['UT'],'L6':['MN','WI','KY']}

for i in dic1.keys():
```

Comment: Try this - ```for k, v in dic1.items():
    print(k, len(v))```

Comment: I wrote your answer.  But, consider reading [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for key in dic1.keys():
    print(key, len(dic1[key]))
```

Or this:

```
for key, value in dic1.items():
    print(key, len(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be this simple loop:

```py
for k, v in dic1.items():
    print(k, len(v))
```

#### Output:

```
L1 4
L2 2
L3 3
L4 4
L5 1
L6 3
```

```py
# or save into a list of tuples:
key_len = [(k, len(v)) for k, v in dic1.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dic1 = {'L1': ['NY', 'CT', 'NH', 'MA'], 
        'L2': ['TX', 'NM'], 
        'L3': ['CA', 'WA', 'AZ'], 
        'L4': ['ND', 'SD','WY', 'ID'],
        'L5': ['UT'],
        'L6': ['MN','WI','KY']}

for key, value in dic1.items():
    print (key + ': ' + str(len(value)))
```

Output:

```
L1: 4
L2: 2
L3: 3
L4: 4
L5: 1
L6: 3
```

Check: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: Suggestion: `print(f"{key}: {len(value)}")`